# What are the pros and cons of different types of shifter cables?

Tags: gears, cable

1. What are the pros and cons of regular and slick gear/shifter cables? I just want easy gear changing. I have shimano gears if that helps. I know the difference between them, but I want to know some pros and cons.
2. What are the pros and cons the stainless steel or galvanised metal cables? I leave it in the shed at night, and when I am not using so it doesn't really get wet all the time. When I ride it often gets wet or muddy. I rarely clean the bike, so it often stays muddy.

Comment: In general, its more about the setup of the cables rather than the cables themselves (assuming they're the right type of cable - for example, never use shifter housing for brake cables) - you need clean cuts on the cable housing and proper routing as well as proper derailleur setup.

Comment: What about rust? Presumably that's the worst enemy? Would you expect e.g. stainless cable to have a longer life span than galvanised cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regular cables:**

Pros:

- inexpensive
- easy to find

cons:

- generally lower quality than slick ones
- much of the time they are not pre-stretched, so they have to wear in.
- heavier

**Slick cables:**

Pros:

- initially slightly faster shifting
- generally come pre-stretched
- lighter

cons:

- (a big one) once the coating wears off, the shifting becomes **A LOT** worse, and the cables need to be changed. This is fairly common if the housing isn't cut right or there is bend when entering/exiting a housing stop.
- very expensive
- installation is harder as the cables are more fragile
- adjustment is more finicky

**Stainless Steel Cables:**

- don't rust
- slightly slicker

**Galvanized:**

- Cheaper
- more bendy